# How am I supposed to rev the engine prior to starting a race?

Tags: gran-turismo-3-a-spec

When I was young and played Gran Turismo 3 and other racing games, I would often hold down the accelerate button before a match started, thinking it would be faster.

Now that I own my own car and drive it, I still don't think I fully understand how to rev the engine before a match.  When I was playing GT3 the other day, I remember that cars will make a distinctive vvvrrRRRRRRR vrrrrrrRRRRRR vvvvvRRRRRRR sound, as if they are pushing on the pedal, then releasing, then pushing back down, then releasing, prior to the race starting.

How am I supposed to rev the engine prior to starting a race? Is it pedal to the medal for GT3? Or should I keep my feet off the accelerator until the race starts?

Comment: I want to upvote this purely because you typed out the revving sounds XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The revving of the engine does allow for more torque to pull out faster.  However, to successfully do this you must find the cars peak RPM, usually 1200-2k before red line or where optimal shifting in manual would be.  Having this info, use the R Analog stick to get to that RPM area by pushing up on the stick.  The button pushing fails quite a bit to the point you overrev the engine and shift into the race a min RPM.

Comment: If I use automatic shifting, what would be your advice? And how do I find the info for the optimal shifting or the cars peak RPM?

Comment: Same thing.  Since Manual give more control on coming out of corners and hill, Auto Trans doesn't change how you rev at start.

Comment: So when the countdown begins, push the R analog stick to get to the optimal RPM, so that when the race starts, there's no delay?

Comment: Yes, you may have to play around again depending on the car.

Comment: So is there a reason why the AI cars will make that sound? The quick rev, quick rev, quick rev

Comment: They are flooring the gas and not letting go.  This is due to a rev limiter being installed in all the games.